# Error in `dplyr::between()`: 'left' must be length 1

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, between

I have a temperature and times database from two weather stations that looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 7
Station Date       Time     Temperature  Tmin  Tmed  Tmax
<chr>   <date>     <time>         <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 F       2021-10-15 00:11:46        16.8  15.2  17.1  20.4
2 F       2021-10-15 00:41:46        16.5  15.2  17.1  20.4
3 F       2021-10-15 01:11:46        16.2  15.2  17.1  20.4
4 F       2021-10-15 01:41:46        15.6  15.2  17.1  20.4
5 F       2021-10-15 02:11:46        15.9  15.2  17.1  20.4
6 F       2021-10-15 02:41:46        16.1  15.2  17.1  20.4
```

here is a reproducible example of the first two days (sorry - I know it's a mess) obtained via `dput()`:

```
structure(list(Station = c("F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F"), Date = structure(c(18915, 
18915, 18915, 18915, 18915, 18915, 18915, 18915, 18915, 18915, 
18915, 18915, 18915, 18915, 18915, 18915, 18915, 18915, 18915, 
18915, 18915, 18915, 18915, 18915, 18915, 18915, 18915, 18915, 
18915, 18915, 18915, 18915, 18915, 18915, 18915, 18915, 18915, 
18915, 18915, 18915, 18915, 18915, 18915, 18915, 18915, 18915, 
18915, 18915, 18916, 18916, 18916, 18916, 18916, 18916, 18916, 
18916, 18916, 18916, 18916, 18916, 18916, 18916, 18916, 18916, 
18916, 18916, 18916, 18916, 18916, 18916, 18916, 18916, 18916, 
18916, 18916, 18916, 18916, 18916, 18916, 18916, 18916, 18916, 
18916, 18916, 18916, 18916, 18916, 18916, 18916, 18916, 18916, 
18916, 18916, 18916, 18916, 18916), class = "Date"), Time = structure(c(706, 
2506, 4306, 6106, 7906, 9706, 11506, 13306, 15106, 16906, 18706, 
20506, 22306, 24106, 25906, 27706, 29506, 31306, 33106, 34906, 
36706, 38506, 40306, 42106, 43906, 45706, 47506, 49306, 51106, 
52906, 54706, 56506, 58306, 60106, 61906, 63706, 65506, 67306, 
69106, 70906, 72706, 74506, 76306, 78106, 79906, 81706, 83506, 
85306, 706, 2506, 4306, 6106, 7906, 9706, 11506, 13306, 15106, 
16906, 18706, 20506, 22306, 24106, 25906, 27706, 29506, 31306, 
33106, 34906, 36706, 38506, 40306, 42106, 43906, 45706, 47506, 
49306, 51106, 52906, 54706, 56506, 58306, 60106, 61906, 63706, 
65506, 67306, 69106, 70906, 72706, 74506, 76306, 78106, 79906, 
81706, 83506, 85306), class = c("hms", "difftime"), units = "secs"), 
Temperature = c(16.8, 16.5, 16.2, 15.6, 15.9, 16.1, 16.4, 
16.2, 16, 16, 16.2, 16.2, 15.9, 16, 16, 16.4, 16.2, 16.5, 
16.1, 16.4, 16.8, 16.6, 18.6, 16.9, 18.6, 19.5, 18.5, 18.5, 
20.4, 19.1, 19.8, 19.7, 18.1, 17.4, 17.4, 16.9, 15.8, 16.8, 
16.9, 16.8, 17, 15.2, 16.2, 17.4, 18.1, 18.3, 18, 17.9, 17.6, 
17.9, 17.7, 17.7, 17.7, 17.8, 18.1, 18.3, 18.1, 16.2, 18, 
18.8, 18.6, 19.1, 18.9, 17.9, 16.2, 17.3, 19.3, 20.2, 20.7, 
20.9, 22.2, 22.3, 21.2, 21.1, 20.1, 23.3, 21.4, 20.2, 19.8, 
18.9, 19.8, 20.1, 20.4, 19.5, 18.8, 18, 17.9, 17.9, 17.8, 
18, 17.9, 16.5, 16.8, 16.5, 16.7, 16.7), Tmin = c(15.2, 15.2, 
15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 
15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 
15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 
15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 
15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 15.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 
16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 
16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 
16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 
16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 
16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2), Tmed = c(17.1, 17.1, 17.1, 17.1, 
17.1, 17.1, 17.1, 17.1, 17.1, 17.1, 17.1, 17.1, 17.1, 17.1, 
17.1, 17.1, 17.1, 17.1, 17.1, 17.1, 17.1, 17.1, 17.1, 17.1, 
17.1, 17.1, 17.1, 17.1, 17.1, 17.1, 17.1, 17.1, 17.1, 17.1, 
17.1, 17.1, 17.1, 17.1, 17.1, 17.1, 17.1, 17.1, 17.1, 17.1, 
17.1, 17.1, 17.1, 17.1, 18.8083333333333, 18.8083333333333, 
18.8083333333333, 18.8083333333333, 18.8083333333333, 18.8083333333333, 
18.8083333333333, 18.8083333333333, 18.8083333333333, 18.8083333333333, 
18.8083333333333, 18.8083333333333, 18.8083333333333, 18.8083333333333, 
18.8083333333333, 18.8083333333333, 18.8083333333333, 18.8083333333333, 
18.8083333333333, 18.8083333333333, 18.8083333333333, 18.8083333333333, 
18.8083333333333, 18.8083333333333, 18.8083333333333, 18.8083333333333, 
18.8083333333333, 18.8083333333333, 18.8083333333333, 18.8083333333333, 
18.8083333333333, 18.8083333333333, 18.8083333333333, 18.8083333333333, 
18.8083333333333, 18.8083333333333, 18.8083333333333, 18.8083333333333, 
18.8083333333333, 18.8083333333333, 18.8083333333333, 18.8083333333333, 
18.8083333333333, 18.8083333333333, 18.8083333333333, 18.8083333333333, 
18.8083333333333, 18.8083333333333), Tmax = c(20.4, 20.4, 
20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 
20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 
20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 
20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 
20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 20.4, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 
23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 
23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 
23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 
23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 
23.3, 23.3, 23.3, 23.3)), row.names = c(NA, -96L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and I would like to add a column to tell me if temperature at given time is close to the daily minimum temperature.

The best way to do this seemed `dplyr::between` function, and I tried to write it like this:

```
TimeTempReprod %>% 
   group_by(Date, Station) %>%
   mutate(y = between(Temperature, Tmin, Tmin + 2))
```

What I get in the console when I run this code is:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `y = dplyr::between(Temperature, Tmin, Tmin + 2)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: Date = 2021-10-15, Station = "F".
Caused by error in `dplyr::between()`:
! `left` must be length 1
```

I tried to look for answers to this problem but I couldn't find it related to the `between` function in other places...

I hope this question is understandable, and I am sorry if it has problems. It is the first question I post to stackexchange after learning from it for two years now, so I still have to learn how to use it properly. Thanks to who will find the time to help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture one value, and `Tmin` is capturing the entire vector of values for each group, so to solve the problem you can use a function that takes out one value out of the vector. Since the vector is made of the same values, many functions can work, e.g. `min`, or `first`:

```r
TimeTempReprod %>% 
  group_by(Date, Station) %>%
  mutate(y = between(Temperature, min(Tmin), min(Tmin) + 2))
```

gives out:

```r
# A tibble: 96 × 8
# Groups:   Date, Station [2]
   Station Date       Time     Temperature  Tmin  Tmed  Tmax y    
   <chr>   <date>     <time>         <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
 1 F       2021-10-15 00:11:46        16.8  15.2  17.1  20.4 TRUE 
 2 F       2021-10-15 00:41:46        16.5  15.2  17.1  20.4 TRUE 
 3 F       2021-10-15 01:11:46        16.2  15.2  17.1  20.4 TRUE 
 4 F       2021-10-15 01:41:46        15.6  15.2  17.1  20.4 TRUE 
 5 F       2021-10-15 02:11:46        15.9  15.2  17.1  20.4 TRUE 
 6 F       2021-10-15 02:41:46        16.1  15.2  17.1  20.4 TRUE 
 7 F       2021-10-15 03:11:46        16.4  15.2  17.1  20.4 TRUE 
 8 F       2021-10-15 03:41:46        16.2  15.2  17.1  20.4 TRUE 
 9 F       2021-10-15 04:11:46        16    15.2  17.1  20.4 TRUE 
10 F       2021-10-15 04:41:46        16    15.2  17.1  20.4 TRUE 
# … with 86 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly, I did not think about it...

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem but I didn't want to group my data. I wanted to compare whether the values of column A were between column B and column C.

```
df %>%
  mutate(is_between = between(A, B, C))
```

However this results in a similar error which brought me to this thread.

The solution is to perform row-wise calcultions:

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(is_between = between(A, B, C)) %>%
  ungroup() # Removes row-wise calculation mode
```

This produced the anticipated results.